# Sonar: Multi-module analysis sonar

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

For our code analysis I want for each maven module one sonar project. 
At the moment I got one sonar project with the modules from parent pom.

For my Jenkins job configuration I use SonarQube Scanner for Maven ([link](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins)) with `sonar-project.properties`.

```
# Root project information
sonar.projectKey=org.mycompany.myproject
sonar.projectName=My Project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Some properties that will be inherited by the modules
sonar.sources=src

# List of the module identifiers
sonar.modules=module1,module2
```

So the expect result for my sonar would be a project one for `module1` and  a project two for `module2`. `module1` and `module2` are both maven module with one parent pom.

```
  myproject
   |
    ->module1
      |
       ->pom.xml (Sonar Project ONE)
    ->module2
      |
       ->pom.xml (Sonar Project TWO)
  ->pom.xml
```

What is the best way to configure this behaviour in **one** jenkins job.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store all modules as standalone projects, then you cannot specify `sonar.modules` and use SonarQube Scanner for Maven. The Maven scanner is designed to create submodules (the same structure as defined in `pom.xml` files).

What you can to do:

1. build all modules by Maven
2. generate in every module's root directory a `sonar-project.properties` file with content:

   ```
   sonar.projectKey=<project.groupId>:<project.artifactId>
   sonar.projectName=<project.name>
   sonar.projectVersion=<project.version>

   sonar.sourceEncoding=<project.build.sourceEncoding>
   sonar.sources=pom.xml,src/main
   sonar.tests=src/test
   sonar.java.binaries=<project.build.directory>/classes
   sonar.java.libraries=<list of all compile and provided libraries>
   sonar.java.test.binaries=<project.build.directory>/classes
   sonar.java.test.libraries=<list of all compile, provided and test libraries>
   ```
3. execute [SonarQube Scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner): `sonar-scanner`

This is very not recommended because:

- makes your project less readable (modules are not "connected")
- executing an analysis is much harder (you have to generate all properties which in standard cases are generated by SonarQube Scanner for Maven)